# Hadoop: How to distribute tasks uniformly to all nodes

Tags: hadoop

i want to distribute task uniformly to all nodes. Is there any way to control this?

Answer (score 2):

A map task will be put on an idle task tracker nearest to the input data.

The priority is:

1. same machine
2. same rack
3. other

In most case, you don't have to worry about the balance problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control:

- where map and reduce tasks are execute
- when map and reduce tasks start or end
- what keys and values are processed by a map task or a reduce task

But, you can control:

- what key are processed by a reduce task and the order in which they occur at reduce (with the partiotioner)

In summary you can't balance only the map tasks, but reduce tasks are balanced by the framework